# typeof operator on Folder returns error

Tags: google-apps-script

In a *google apps script* function, I have a `Folder` parameter. So, this statement

```
Logger.log(typeof folder);
```

logs 'undefined' when the parameter is not supplied, which is right. But when a folder is supplied, I get this error:

> Invalid JavaScript value of type $Proxy686. (line 15)

Not able to diagnose why. Need some help. Thanks.

Sanjay

*Update*: Here is the code reproducing the issue:

```
function typeOfTest() {

  var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++)
    Logger.log(typeof folders[i]);

};
```

Comment: Could you please to provide a minimum script which is possible to copy-and-paste to the script editor and reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated my post to add the code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

In fact. I have the same behavior. I don't know either it is a bug or a feature. A possible workaround is to use the Folder's `toString()` function. Something like

```
function typeOfTest() {

  var folders = DocsList.getAllFolders();
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++)
    Logger.log(folders[i].toString());

};
```

Comment: That was a sample snippet to reproduce the error. Actually, I have something like `if (typeof folder == 'undefined')` to test whether a `folder` parameter is available. Any workaround for it? Thanks.

Comment: @Sanjay. My code is not the same as yours. The difference is `typeof folders[i]` in your code and `folders[i].toString()`. The `DocsList.getAllFolders()` returns only folders and the result list contains only the `Folder` instances.

Comment: @Sanjay. A workaround for your code `if (typeof folder == 'undefined')` is `if (folder == undefined)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I 'll try `if (folder == undefined)`.